# OMNET ++, How to pass message between two car in VEINS?

Tags: omnet++

I am new in VEINS. I can run a sumo simulation in Veins but don't know hot to communicate or pass message between cars. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The demo scenario that is used in the Veins tutorial does exactly that. You can find the tutorial on [the Veins website](http://veins.car2x.org/tutorial/), the application code in [TraCIDemo11p.cc](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4a2/src/veins/modules/application/traci/TraCIDemo11p.cc#L94)

Comment: Thank you for reply. The thing is that I don't know how to write a custom/sample code that will pass message between two vehicles. Can u please help from where I can begin?

Comment: I've edited the answer to include a link to the demo source code. You can use it as a reference of how to send and receive data

Comment: @Md.amirulIslam if you have not done the TicToc tutorial, then make sure to start from there: https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/tictoc-tutorial/

Comment: Thank you. I have done that tutorial and also know basics about writing codes in omnet++. But the problem is I don't know how to declare a vehicle module in VEINS or how to access sumo vehicles initialize or handle message function in VEINS. That's why I am failing to start coding there.

Comment: When you run the  tutorial simulation, you will see vehicles being colored green when they receive a message. If you look at the code I linked from the answer, you can see how this is achieved - the code to change the color is triggered when a vehicle handles a data message. You can change this code if you want the vehicle to do something different when handling received data. The initialize method is at the top of the code I linked. It is called "initialize". You can change it if you want something different done during initialization of the car's application.

Comment: hi I need a help again. lets say i want to know the current node id or name in veins initialize function likewise omnet++ getFullName() or getName. How can i do that in veins?

Comment: I got it its findHost()->getFullName(). special thanks to Christoph Sommer Sir.